# Change "Sign In through Steam" logo after authentication

Tags: python, flask, steam

I'm following [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/42/) tutorial that shows how to Sign In through Steam in  Flask based websites. So the question is how can I remove "Sign In through Steam" logo when the user logged in and to show his username instead of it ? And do the opposite thing when he logged out ? What I have in my html template now:

```
<li><a href="/login"><input type="image" name="SignIn" value="SignIn" src="static/steam.png"/></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mentioned tutorial the current user object stored in `g.user` variable:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = None
    if 'user_id' in session:
        g.user = User.query.get(session['user_id'])
```

This `g` global variable [is available](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#standard-context) in Jinja2 templates as well. Thus you can do the following in the template:

```
{% if g.user is defined and g.user is not none %}
{# User has logged in #}
<li>Hello, {{ g.user.nickname }}!</li>
<li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>

{% else %}
{# User has not logged in #}
<li><a href="/login"><input type="image" name="SignIn" value="SignIn" src="static/steam.png"/></a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It almost works, but instead of the username it returns "VARCHAR(80)".

Comment: Strange, it should work (`g.user.nickname` is used in the tutorial as well). Does the nickname have a correct value in the database?

Comment: @Steve: if you use my solution in your code and additionally ask a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33806118/getting-varchar80-from-db-instead-of-nickname) containing the code above, then at least you should accept my answer as well. :)

Comment: yep, thank you, I completely forgot to accept your answer, it helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe we can do this with the `session` dict.

```
{% if not session.logged_in %}
<li><a href="/login"><input type="image" name="SignIn" value="SignIn" src="static/steam.png"/></a></li>
{% else %}
<li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
{% endif %}
```