# Getting VARCHAR(80) from db instead of nickname

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm using code from [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/42/) to Sign In my web-site using Steam. I need to get the username of the user after authentication. What I have in html template:

```
{% if g.user is defined and g.user is not none %}
{# User has logged in #}
<li>Hello, {{ g.user.nickname }}!</li>
<li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>

{% else %}
{# User has not logged in #}
<li><a href="/login"><input type="image" name="SignIn" value="SignIn" src="static/steam.png"/></a></li>
{% endif %}
```

But this returns VARCHAR(80) instead of the username. What's my mistake ?
**EDIT**. Here is the code from the example that I mentioned:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, session, json, g, flash
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.openid import OpenID
import urllib
import re

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'A0Zr98j/3yX R~XHH!jmN]LWX/,?RT'
Bootstrap(app)
app.config.from_pyfile('settings.cfg')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
oid = OpenID(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    steam_id = db.Column(db.String(40))
    nickname = db.String(80)

    @staticmethod
    def get_or_create(steam_id):
        rv = User.query.filter_by(steam_id=steam_id).first()
        if rv is None:
            rv = User()
            rv.steam_id = steam_id
            db.session.add(rv)
        return rv

db.create_all()

def get_steam_userinfo(steam_id):
    options = {
        'key': app.config['STEAM_API_KEY'],
        'steamids': steam_id
    }
    url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/' \
          'GetPlayerSummaries/v0001/?%s' % urllib.urlencode(options)
    rv = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
    return rv['response']['players']['player'][0] or {}

_steam_id_re = re.compile('steamcommunity.com/openid/id/(.*?)$')

@app.route('/login')
@oid.loginhandler
def login():
    if g.user is not None:
        return redirect(oid.get_next_url())
    return oid.try_login('http://steamcommunity.com/openid')

@oid.after_login
def create_or_login(resp):
    match = _steam_id_re.search(resp.identity_url)
    g.user = User.get_or_create(match.group(1))
    steamdata = get_steam_userinfo(g.user.steam_id)
    g.user.nickname = steamdata['personaname']
    db.session.commit()
    session['user_id'] = g.user.id
    return redirect(oid.get_next_url())

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = None
    if 'user_id' in session:
        g.user = User.query.get(session['user_id'])

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template('mainpage.html')

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('user_id', None)
    return redirect(oid.get_next_url())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Maybe you can reduce it to `{% if g.user %}`. I can't see what `defined` means and shouldn't it be `None` instead of `none`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define `User.nickname` as a column, you just assigned a SQL type to it.  Change it to be a column with that type.

```
nickname = db.Column(db.String)
```